# decodeHex method not found on Device, but working on Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, apache-commons

I'm working on the project with RSA encryption, and need to use the method from Apache commons-codec, which is:

- Hex.encodeHex(byte[])
- Hex.decodeHex(String)

Both methods are working fine on Android emulator, but it will return NoSuchMethodError on Device

```
public String RSADecrypt(final String message) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getPrivateKey());
            byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(Hex.decodeHex(message));
            return new String(decryptedBytes);
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DecoderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method decodeHex(Ljava/lang/String;)[B in class Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)
```

- My emulator run on Pie, Oreo, & Nougat
- My device run on Nougat & Marshmallow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some Android versions contain an older version of the Apache commons-codec library (1.3) where the `decodeHex(String)` method didn't yet exist. Try calling `decodeHex(char[])` instead. I.e. modify your code like this:

```
byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(Hex.decodeHex(message.toCharArray()));
```

That should work with commons-codec v1.3.

Comment: Thanks, it working. So this problem related to OS issue.

Comment: Yes. As I understand it, Android itself contains the commons-codec library which is used even if your application contains a newer version of the same library. Often the version used is 1.3.

Also if you're happy with the answer, could you please mark it as accepted? Thanks.